# Is there a command that lets me quickly close and reopen multiple files in different locations, similar to how pushd popd work?

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, files

I want to be able to edit several files quickly. It would be great if there is a tool that allows me to stack files similar to how `pushd` and `popd` does. Does such a tool exist? If not, what do you suggest?

In my mind I should be able to list the files in my stack with something like this.

```
files -v
  0 /etc/bind/named.conf.options
  1 /etc/default/bind9
  2 /etc/bind/named.conf.local
```

Then open the file for editing with something like this.

```
nano ~2
```

I have found that I can edit multiple files at once, but this isn't the same. If I open several files like `nano ./test.txt /etc/another_test.txt` I would need to close and save each open file to exit out of nano in order to preform another action, like test the change. This doesn't really save me from relying on the history command to reopen files or multiple tty's to test the changes.

Comment: please do not use comments to add information that should be in the question ... use the edit button instead ... or click this link ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/584831/edit

Comment: @user5125644 can't you background (Ctrl-Z) nano instead of exiting? (That can be done with Vim, for example.) Or, both Vim and emacs have terminals built-in to them, so you can run a shell inside the editor.

Comment: From the title I thought you wanted to edit at the same time. But when I continued to read, it looks like you want to be able to switch between files quickly. Is that correct?

Comment: jsotola, thanks responding and helping me use the site correctly. I will be sure to use the edit page to update the post in the future.

Comment: muru Thanks for responding, in nano if i press ctrl+z i get a message about being disabled, and ctl+c show the cursors position.

Comment: ctrl-alt-delor Sorry for the confusion, I updated the question, I hope its more clear now. Yes you are correct I want to be able to switch between files quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you in Bash:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

filelist=()

function fadd() {
    filelist+=("${@}")
}

function fdel() {
    local -r index="${1}"
    newstack=()

    for ((i = 0; i < ${#filelist[@]}; ++i)); do
        if [[ "${i}" != "${index}" ]]; then
            newstack+=( "${filelist[${i}]}" )
        fi
    done

    filelist=( "${newstack[@]}" )
}

function flist() {
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#filelist[@]}; ++i)); do
        printf "%2d %s\n" "${i}" "${filelist[${i}]}"
    done
}

function fedit() {
    local -r index="${1:-0}"

    ${EDITOR} "${filelist[${index}]}"
}

function fget() {
    local -r index="${1:-0}"

    echo "${filelist[${index}]}"
}
```

This defines an array `filelist` that is initially empty, and defines a set of functions that act on that array:

- The `fadd()` function appends names to the end of the array.
- The `fdel()` function removes an element of the array given its index.
- The `flist()` function lists the content of the array along with their index.
- The `fedit()` function opens your editor (as defined by `${EDITOR}`) with the file corresponding to the given index into `filelist`.
- The `fget()` function prints the filename for the file at the given index.

Note that this doesn't include any error checking (e.g., you can supply invalid indices).  Note also that I didn't test this with spaces in filenames -- that probably won't go well at all with this.

If I source a file that contains the above, then I can do the following:

```
$ source file_mgmt

# Add some files of interest
$ fadd ~/src/foo.[ch]
$ fadd /tmp/bar.txt
$ fadd ~/.bashrc

# View the file list
$ flist
 0 /home/user/src/foo.c
 1 /home/user/src/foo.h
 2 /tmp/bar.txt
 3 /home/user/.bashrc

# Open a file from the list by index
$ fedit 0
[ my ${EDITOR} opened with /home/user/src/foo.c ]

# Remove a file from the list
$ fdel 2

$ flist
 0 /home/user/src/foo.c
 1 /home/user/src/foo.h
 2 /home/user/.bashrc

# Copy ~/.bashrc to tmp
$ cp $(fget 2) /tmp
```

Note that the file list would be on a per-shell basis.  If, for example, you had multiple terminals open, they would have independent file lists.

Comment: Andy Dalton - Thank you so much! I just included your script into my bashrc and it works great!